# JavaScript syntax doubt? (mootools)

Tags: javascript, mootools

EDIT: This got way too complicated, I will migrate this question to another question and put up my new code there! Please ignore the code on this because it is logically flawed. (Please vote to close the question as it makes no sense)

Hi,

I am initializing the following loops in my code. The code is written using mootools.

```
CANVAS.init({ canvasElement : 'canvas', interactive : true });

var itemlayer = CANVAS.layers.add({ id : 'items' });

for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {

    itemlayer.add({

        id : 'item-'+i + '-' + j,
        x : 51 * i,
        y : 51 * j,
        w : 50,
        h : 50,
        state : 'normal',
        interactive : true,
        colors : { normal : '#f00', hover : '#00f' },
        events : {
            onDraw : function(ctx){

                    ctx.fillStyle = this.colors[this.state];
                    ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);

                    this.setDims(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
            }
        }

    });


}

}



/* object that hold the information whether a certain object
 * is in animation right now or not. This is used to prevent
 * multiple Cmorph instances working on the same item
 * */

  var locked= {};
  for(i= 0; i<6; i++)
  for(j= 0; j<6; j++)
  {
    itemid = 'item-'+i+'-'+j;
    itemid : false,
  }
    //then once I have done that
    //animate all items with the function given below

    function animate()
    {
   for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        for(j=0;j<6;j++)
        {
          itemid = 'item-'+i+'-'+j;
          if(locked.itemid)return;  //guess even this will return errors!
      locked.itemid = true;
      var item = CANVAS.layers.get('myLayer').get(itemid);

                  new Cmorph(item,{
                    duration : 1000,
                    transition : 'bounce:out',
                    onComplete : function()
                    {
                        locked.itemid = false;
                    }
                }
      ).morph({
        y : (item.y == 50?375:50),
        scale : (item.scale == 1?2:1)
    });
       }
    }

    CANVAS.addThread(new Thread({
            id : 'myThread',
            onExec : function(){
                    CANVAS.clear().draw();
            }
    }));​
```

Is my syntax correct and will all the id's get locked or am I going to have errors. Also if I am making a mistake, could you please correct me. I know this is a very dumb doubt, but please bear with me! thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by "locking", but the syntax has some errors. This is how i would do this:

```
var locked = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        locked.push("item-"+i+"-"+j);
    }
}
```

It constructs an array of strings, holding your item-string.

You cannot use normal code statements inside of JSON (`{}`). You need to create it, and populate it afterwards, if you need this (more complex) behaviour.

**EDIT:** According to your clarification: I can spot a single syntax error at the end: Your inner `for`-loop is missing his closing `}`. On the other hand, i do not know mootools in detail, so there might be mootools-related problems left.

Comment: I adjusted my post according to your changes.

Comment: hey thanks! I guess I will have to wait for someone with mootools experience to come and sort this out for me now :)

Comment: Why don't you simply test it using firebug? This will report any errors with a line-number.

Comment: I am using chrome to do so. They report the errors. Even when the errors are gone, I don't see my desired output!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have object locked. Instead you can use array as locked -

```
var locked = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) { 
    for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) { 
        var itemStr = "item-"+i+"-"+j;
        locked.push(itemStr); 
    } 
}
```

This will store all your IDs in the array locked and you can access using `locked[index]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say "locking", but are you trying to create an object that uses the `itemid`s as properties, which are set to false?

```
/* create empty object */
var locked = {};
/* loop & populate */
for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        var itemStr = "item-" + i + "-" + j;
        locked[itemStr] = false;
    }
}

/* use id */
if(!locked["item-0-0"]) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question, please take a look and comment again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question, but I think you might mean:

```
var locked= {};
for(i= 0; i<6; i++)
    for(j= 0; j<6; j++)
        locked['item-'+i+'-'+j]= false;
```

Names in JavaScript `{name: value}` object literals are limited to quoted strings or unquoted literal names taken as strings and not general expressions. So you can't have a variable name in an object literal. Instead you have to write the property after creation, using `[]` access. (`a['b']` is the same as `a.b`.)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I assume that I can define the locked state for all the functions using your method as the other. But please take a look at the animate function. Do you think I will be able to loop it the way I did. Will that throw syntax errors too?

Comment: I have attached your code to my program, could you please take a look and tell me, if the code looks fine now? thanks.

Comment: You are saying `locked.itemid`: this means the property *called* `itemid`! You mean `locked[itemid]`, the property whose name is held in the `itemid` variable.

Comment: Too many syntaxing errors! Please edit the question as you see right! I am getting baffled by the sheer number of syntax errors I keep ending up with!